# Part of the mesh disapeared when using a square selection "B"?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was selecting vertices to merge them and was using the square selection "B", and suddenly everything disapeared but the selected square. I thing I must have pressed other button by mistake, but do not know how to recover the normal view...does anyone know?

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Doesn't you accidentally hit Alt+B? Alt+B is clipping border, hit it another time to reset view.

Comment: Hi!, thanks! yes, it was that had happened i think, and did what you say and worked! thanks a lot! greetings!

Comment: Hey! I´ve seen a tuto showing what clipping border is and is really useful! i didn´t know it. Thanks a lot